# Выдает ошибку. Python (функции def)

Tags: python, python-3.x, функции

Что не так? Дает написать одно число, а потом вылазит ошибка об не существовании "с1"[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Неужели сделать скрин проще, чем скопировать код?

Comment: ну для начала прилагайте код в формате текста, пожалуйста. А второе - сообщение об ошибке тоже не помешало бы

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, при написании кода вы написали `c1` один раз с английской `c`, а в другой раз с русской.

Поправьте в обоих местах, чтобы точно и там и там была английская `c` и всё должно заработать.